# Log4Net output to Mongo

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, log4net, log4net-configuration

Does anyone had the luck to have this configured correctly?

- Created an account on [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/home)
- Added a new user [to the database](http://balexandre.com/temp/2011-10-27_1425.png)
- Created a new Collection named `logs_net`
- Added [log4mongo-net library](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/log4mongo-net)
- Added the configuration to the `web.config`

`<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />`

and

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="MongoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.MongoDBAppender, log4mongo-net">
     <!-- MongoDB connection options -->
     <host value="staff.mongohq.com" />
     <port value="10048" />
     <databaseName value="d1741d63-46b1-4a44-9c21-8a85cecae45b" />
     <collectionName value="logs_net" />
     <userName value="balexandre" />
     <password value="myPassWorD" />
  </appender>
```

- Added `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` to `global.asax` under `Application_Start()`

and added some info:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
logger.Info("MainController Initialize test");
```

And... I can't get logs into MongoDB, **any help?**

By the way, the Database name is not the correct one, neither the password, and if I use `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender` it works great.

Comment: Could be a firewall issue if you're running MongoDB on port 10048.  Can you connect to MongoDB from other parts of your app?

Comment: yes I can, I'm using [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/) and I can connect with a client gui to the database. Firewall is disabled on my machine, and this also happens if I `push` the source to the hosting.

Comment: Honestly it may be fairly straightforward to grab the [source](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net/tree/master/src) and debug through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest turning on [internal debugging](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug), this should reveal what is going wrong. It is quite possible that the log4mongo assembly is not loaded correctly. Are you sure it is copied (with all dependencies) to the bin folder?

Comment: dang... that was easy :D and I wasted sooo much time on this, all I was missing was the libraries :-/ ohh my head!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms for a different reason. My XML logging configuration was wrong. Here is how I found out.

1) Enable internal (not log4net) debugging in the code before logger is created:

```
log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;
...
XmlElement conf = ...
XmlConfigurator.Configure(conf);
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
```

2) Run your code and see output in Visual Studio `Output` window with `Debug` selected in `Show output from` dropdown. You should be able to see how Appenders are constructed.

In my case database url was wrong - I specified additional options in a bad format.